# google maps click on marker to open URL from a database

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to have a map show attractions on a map. The markers are pulled from a database and are put on a map. However, I want to display a website (put in the database) after clicking the right marker. I got the code to open a different page, however, it only shows the ID/URL of the last line in the database table. how can I make it so that it would display the URL or ID of each location instead of just the last location?

the code I have right now:

```
    function load() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      //defining the location
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.466963, 9.188733),
    //defining default map zoom
    zoom: 14,
    //disable scroll wheel function
    scrollwheel: false,
    //disable navigation control
    navigationControl: false,
    //disable map type control
    mapTypeControl: false,
    //disable scaling function
    scaleControl: false,
    //allowing the map to be dragable
    draggable: true,
    //disable user interface e.g. + and - buttons for zoom control
    disableDefaultUI: true

  });
  //creates window that contains defined information
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;


  //pulling the data from the file
  downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml2.php", function(data) {

     //defining variables using data pulled over


    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 1; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
        var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
        var idd = markers[i].getAttribute("identity");
        var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon
        });
      //when marker is clicked, it opens the URL of the location
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                        window.open(idd, '_blank');
                        }); 
    }
  });
}
```

I have tried several options to no avail, if I would need to provide more info, please do say so, I'm at an impasse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save the "identity" value with each marker. You can add custom data to a marker when constructing it:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        idd:idd
    });
```

then the listener should use this new property:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
     window.open(this.idd, '_blank');
});
```